# How can I insert bytes with OllyDbg?

Tags: windows, ollydbg, executable

I am developing a game in [GameMaker: Studio](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfhva9hMLVAhXnz4MKHcsUD_IQFgg6MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoyogames.com%2Fgamemaker&usg=AFQjCNFQQRqeb2TlvDKbVKlNMM1C55-9fA) and have run into a minor problem. No matter what I do, the games output payload is generated, named, and referenced as `data.win`. I would like to name it something other than `data.win` and still be able to run it. I have been able to pinpoint the reference of the payload in the game's executable with OllyDbg, but am, of course, limited to modifying the value with only eight bytes. I know it is possible to insert bytes in OllyDbg, but I can't figure out how.

[image: Here is the value I found in referenced strings]

I was able to change the extension successfully, but only that. I did this to ensure that modifying this value directly *actually* works.

*Yes*, I am *completely aware* that this has the *potential* to break the executable, but it is a risk I am willing to make. I have already used `Binary edit` both with, and without the `Keep size` box checked. I am still somewhat new to OllyDbg, so any help is grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So you are trying to modify a string, increasing it's size? You actually can insert more than 8 bytes there if you uncheck "Keep size" box and continue typing bytes as usual (don't forget to insert 0 byte at the end of a string), but you will end up with corrupting following data (next string in your case)

Here you have 2 solutions:

1. Forget about your next string, corrupt it
2. Create you file name string in some other empty space in memory, modify all references to your original "data.win" string to reference your new string (you can find all references by RMB click at the begining of a string -> Find references to -> Selected block), and save modified executable

Comment: I modified the string using the first method (that's usually what  I do), but if it exceeds eight bytes the executable can no longer locate the payload. Overwriting the neighboring string doesn't seem to be ideal. Is there perhaps a way to insert additional bytes that will shift the rest of the data over by as many bytes that are inserted? Your second option sounds promising, but I don't even know where to start on it.

Comment: How do you think you can shift the data? It is impossible. If your program knows that some specific variable is located at adress 1D400, you can't simply shift it, you will invalidate basically EVERYTHING. "executable can no longer locate the payload" - what does it mean? Can you explain in more details? Everything should be okay, just rewrite that next useless string. Or if you don't want to, you have an extremely complicated solution. If you are still interested in it, i can try to explain it, but you will still have to do the work by yourself

Comment: If the payload remains as `data.win`, the game will run automatically and normally. If however, the payload is named to something _other than_ "`data.win`", the executable brings up `explorer.exe` and asks the user to manually browse for the payload. Now, this method _does_ work, but is obviously not as stream-lined. I have overwritten the next string, but by doing so the executable asks to browse again. I believed that shifting the data was necessary because I believe the `data.win` value needs to be in the location it is currently in, while retaining the bytes between the next string.

Comment: String is a variable that consists of chars, ending with special bytes 0x00 0x00  to indicate the end of a string (in your case it may be 4 0 bytes like 00000000 because it is compiler dependent). If you have extended it's length, everything should work properly. If your executable can't find the file, there are a lot reasons it can't. Maybe there is another string "data.win" that is referencing this file, or the file simply does not exist

Comment: Please provide some screenshots, i have no idea what have you modified, thus i can't properly help you